# AWS Polly Integration SDKs

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I just came across the announcement about [Amazon Polly text-to-speech service](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/). I am able to access the service in the AWS console, but I cannot find any integration points. There aren't any links in the console to access APIs / SDKs.

The [v3 documentation for the AWS .NET SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html) doesn't include docs for Polly either.

Are there SDKs for .NET, for Amazon Polly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/developers/#sdk)?
Currently, in Amazon Polly Developer Guide ([pdf](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/polly-dg.pdf) / [html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/examples-for-using-polly.html)) you can find examples for python, android, iOS. After installing SDK you can find `C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net45\AWSSDK.Polly.dll` that contains all the classes to use Polly.

Here is a simple example I've just played with:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        AmazonPollyClient client = new AmazonPollyClient();

        // Create describe voices request.
        DescribeVoicesRequest describeVoicesRequest = new DescribeVoicesRequest();
        // Synchronously ask Amazon Polly to describe available TTS voices.
        DescribeVoicesResponse describeVoicesResult = client.DescribeVoices(describeVoicesRequest);
        List<Voice> voices = describeVoicesResult.Voices;


        // Create speech synthesis request.
        SynthesizeSpeechRequest synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest();
        // Text
        synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest.Text = "Hello world!";
        // Select voice for synthesis.
        synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest.VoiceId = voices[0].Id;
        // Set format to MP3.
        synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Mp3;
        // Get the presigned URL for synthesized speech audio stream.
        var presignedSynthesizeSpeechUrl = client.SynthesizeSpeechAsync(synthesizeSpeechPresignRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        using (FileStream output = File.OpenWrite("hello_world.mp3"))
        {
            presignedSynthesizeSpeechUrl.AudioStream.CopyTo(output);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

It returns mp3 encoded audio file with the text you specify.